# Maximizing the minimum of $k$ submodular functions

Tags: algorithms, approximation

Let $f(X)$ be a monotone submodular function from $2^{\{1, \ldots, n\}}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and consider the problem of maximizing it subject to a cardinality constraint $|X| \leq m$. By using the greedy algorithm, it is possible to obtain a $1-1/e$ approximation (see, for example, [these lecture notes](http://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/CS369P-files/lec16.pdf)).

But now suppose $f_1(X), \ldots, f_k(X)$ are monotone submodular functions and we want to maximize $\min(f_1(X), \ldots, f_k(X))$ subject to the same cardinality constraint. Is it still possible to obtain a constant factor approximation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Krause, McMahan, Guestrin and Gupta](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/krause08b/krause08b.pdf), who call this problem *Robust Submodular Observation Selection* show that is is NP-hard to approximate this problem to within *any* constant.